# Change from universal serial bus controllers to COM port

Tags: usb, drivers, python3, device-manager, com

When I plug my USB device it is recognized as universal serial bus controllers in device manager but I would like to be on COM port because I would like to use python script to control it. It works fine with original software provided by company. Is there possibility to assign COM port to USB device?

I would like to use this module: https://pypi.org/project/ThorlabsPM100/